# Effectively blocking flash online games

Tags: lan, opendns, web-filtering

How do I block all games on one computer? hosts file is an option, but I have yet to come across a decent hosts list for all online game sites.

I tried using open DNS but the filer list there is terrible for games and most sites are available even though they are blocked.

What would you use?

BTW, the OS is windows 8.

Comment: Don't allow flash plugins to be installed or run?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but then youtube etc cannot work which is a problem.

Comment: In Firefox, you can make flash videos (like youtube) work with VLC plugin, maybe there's one too for IE.
BTW, I think that flash games are mostly SWF files, so maybe you can block it with some firewall or filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to block Flash games, your best bet is to uninstall/prohibit Flash Player. Many videos on YouTube can be viewed using its HTML5 player.

Having said that, there are numerous non-Flash based online games, so you will never have a solution that does not require constant human oversight.